# ajax form is_valid returns false (django)

Tags: ajax, django, forms, submit

I cannot figure out why my form is returning false to is_valid

i have a page called account that has an ajax function to submit a form

i pass my form in on my account view and my createform view

createform view: this is where my ajax is handled

```
def createrecipe(request):
    print "entering createrecipeview"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "form is a post"
        form = RecipeForm(request.POST)
        print form.errors
        if form.is_valid():
            print "form is valid"
            form = RecipeForm(initial = {'original_cookbook' : request.user.cookbooks.all()[0]})
            form = form.save()
            if form.cleaned_data['reset_recipe'] == "True":
                print "reset recipe"
                form = RecipeForm(initial = {"original_cookbook": request.user.cookbooks.all()[0]})
                t = loader.get_template('cookbook/create_form.html')
                c = RequestContext(request, {
                'form': form,
                })

                data = {
                'replace': True,
                'form': t.render(c),
                'success': False,
                }

                json = simplejson.dumps(data)
                return HttpResponse(json,mimetype='text/plain')
            t = loader.get_template('cookbook/create_form.html')
            c = RequestContext(request, {
            'form': form,
            })

            data = {
            'replace': True,
            'form': t.render(c),
            'success': True,
            }

            json = simplejson.dumps(data)
            return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='text/plain')
        else:
            print "form is invalid"
            form = RecipeForm(request.POST)
            t = loader.get_template('cookbook/create_form.html')
            c = RequestContext(request, {
                'form':form,
            })

            data ={
                'form': t.render(c),
                'success': False,
            }

            json = simplejson.dumps(data)
            return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='text/plain')
```

account view: this is where i pass in the form for the ajax view

```
def account(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        cookbooks = user.cookbooks
        if cookbooks.all().exists():
            cookbook = cookbooks.all()[0]
            form = RecipeForm(request.POST)
            recipe_list = cookbook.recipes.all()
        else:
            raise Http404
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/login')
    t = loader.get_template('cookbook/account.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {
        'form': form,
        'recipe_list': recipe_list
    })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

so my question is when when using ajax with django what view do i need to pass the form in on 
the page that has the ajax js or the page that has the form on it

sorry if this is confusing - if it doesn't make sense please tell me and i will elaborate

here is my form.errors print

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>name<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>ingredients<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field cannot be null.</li></ul></li><li>author<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>steps<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field cannot be null.</li></ul></li><li>prep_time<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>type<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

this actually makes sense since i am not adding any input to the form it is not validating

sorry but i believe this was a false alarm

here is my js

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    var form = $('form#createrecipeform');
    form.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('ajax form submission function called successfully.');
    form = $(this);
    console.log(form)
    var serialized_form = form.serialize();
        $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: serialized_form, 
            success: (function(data) { 
                console.log('ajax success function called successfully.');
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                if (data.success) {
                    console.log('success');//i dont know what to do here
                    var newForm = data.form;
                    form.replaceWith(newForm);
                } else {
                    console.log('failure');// i also don't know what to do here
                    var newForm = data.form;
                    form.replaceWith(newForm);  
                }
            })
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

katie

Comment: More clarification would indeed help. You could post the relevant JS . Also, you should be debugging this by printing `form.errors`, returning the error on ajax error and logging it in JS, etc., The form will tell you exactly why it's not valid.

Comment: thank you for that helpful piece of information about form.errors

Comment: can you help me understand with ajax where i should be passing my form in - should i be passing it in on the page that calls the ajax and the page that submits the form or both or what? thanks

Comment: looks like the form is missing a lot of required fields. You will have to show your javascript code and probably HTML to determine what's wrong. You'd need the form in the template only on the first page. Your ajax view only __handles__ data - the form is only needed in python

Comment: i have uploaded my javascript but i think what was wrong is that i had a lot of missing fields in the form because right now i am trying to reset the form when i close the div (getting rid of all of the "this field is required" warnings) instead of resetting the form it redirects me to the form action page

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are sending every not-null fields. Sometimes you are sending data with incorrect property names or you are missing a required field. To check what's going on I suggest to enter data using the shell and accessing the error list for forms. To do that

```
$python manage.py shell 
>>> from yourapp.models import yourClass 
>>> data = {'name':'Jefrey','age':27,'home':'NYC'}
>>> f = yourClass(data)
>>> f.is_valid()
```

If you get False , do this

```
>>>f.errors
```

That way you will see what is going on. More about that at Django documentation 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/

I hope this helps